# Passing unicode sf::String into std::filesystem::u8path

Tags: c++, filesystems, c++17, sfml

I was trying to get `sf::String` into `std::filesystem::u8path`. My first method is converting it into an `std::string`, `(std::string)sfstringbar` but it sees it as a single byte character, i also tried `auto x = sfstringbar.toUtf8()` `std::string(x.begin(), x.end())` but the same. My second method is to pass it as a `char` array which hopefully could read it with the UTF 8 encoding, but still the same happens.

EDIT:

```
char* makeutf8str(str string) {
    std::basic_string<sf::Uint8> utf8 = string.toUtf8();
    std::vector<char>* out = new std::vector<char>;
    for (auto x = utf8.begin(); x != utf8.end(); x++) {
        out->push_back(*x);
    }
    return &(out->at(0));
}

bool neaxfile::isfile(str file) {
    std::cout << "\nThis: " << makeutf8str(file) << "\n";
    return std::filesystem::is_regular_file(std::filesystem::u8path(makeutf8str(file)));
}
```

Here's about the second solution i tried. I have a file called `Яyes.txt` as an example, but when i pass in to check if it exists, it says it doesn't. Because the `makeutf8str()` function splits `Я` into `Ð` and `¯`. I can't seem to get the encoder to work properly.

EDIT 2:

```
str neaxfile::getcwd() {
    std::error_code ec;
    str path = std::filesystem::current_path(ec).u8string();
    if (ec.value() == 0) {
        return path;
    } else {
        return '\0';
    }
}

std::vector<str> neaxfile::listfiles() {
    std::vector<str> res;
    for (auto entry : std::filesystem::directory_iterator((std::string)neaxfile::getcwd())) {
        if (neaxfile::isfile(entry.path().wstring())) res.push_back(entry.path().wstring());
    }
    return res;
}
```

I tried the first solution below. It no longer prints `Ð¯`. But it still doesn't confirm that this is a file. I tried to list the files using that ^

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please [edit] your question to include a [mcve], which also show the string you try to "convert" and how you check the result (as well as what that result is).

Comment: What "same thing happens?" Is this a compile error or is it not doing the right thing? Provide the code you're using and explain *exactly* what you get.

Comment: I've provided that now

Comment: The `makeutf8str` function have two problems: The first is the memory leak, you create a `std::vector` dynamically, but you have no way to `delete` it; The second problem is that the output operator `<<` treats `char*` as a null-terminated byte string, but the vector won't have such a terminator.

Comment: I'm aware of both of that. I was unsure about those at the time, so i didn't think much at the time. All i care about was getting it to work, however i don't know how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`std::filesystem::u8path()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/u8path) "Constructs a path `p` from a UTF-8 encoded sequence of `char`s [or `char8_t`s (since C++20)], **supplied either as an `std::string`, or as `std::string_view`, or as a null-terminated multibyte string, or as a [first, last) iterator pair.**"

A `std::string` can hold a UTF-8 encoded char sequence (better to use `std::u8string` in C++20, though).  [`sf::String::ToUtf8()`](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1String.php#a9e12e9c568994e6df06962cf49180699) returns a UTF-8 encoded `std::basic_string<Uint8>`.  You can simply cast the `UInt8` data to `char` to construct a `std::string`, there is no need for your `makeutf8str()` function to use `std::vector<char>` or return a raw `char*` at all (especially since it is leaking the `std::vector` anyway).

You can use the `std::string` constructor that takes a `char*` and a `size_t` as input, eg:

```cpp
std::string makeutf8str(const str &string) {
    auto utf8 = string.toUtf8();
    return std::string(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(utf8.c_str()), utf8.size());
}
```

Or, you can use the `std::string` constructor that takes a range of iterators as input (despite your claim, this should work just fine), eg:

```cpp
std::string makeutf8str(const str &string) {
    auto utf8 = string.toUtf8();
    return std::string(utf8.begin(), utf8.end());
}
```

Either way will work fine with `std::cout` and `std::filesystem::u8path()`, eg:

```cpp
bool neaxfile::isfile(const str &file) {
    auto utf8 = makeutf8str(file);
    std::cout << "\nThis: " << utf8 << "\n";
    return std::filesystem::is_regular_file(std::filesystem::u8path(utf8));
}
```

That being said, the Unicode character `Я` is encoded in UTF-8 as bytes `0xD0 0xAF`, which when *interpreted* as Latin-1 instead of UTF-8 will appear as `Ð¯`.  This means the `std::string` data is properly UTF-8 encoded, it is just not being processed correctly.  For instance, if your console cannot handle UTF-8 output, then you will see `Ð¯` instead of `Я`.  But, `u8path()` should process the UTF-8 encoded `std::string` just fine, and convert it to the filesystem's native encoding as needed.  But then, there is no guarantee that the underlying filesystem will actually handle a Unicode filename like `Яyes.txt` properly, but that would be an OS issue, not a C++ issue.

---

**UPDATE**: your `listfiles()` function is not making use of UTF-8 at all when using `directory_iterator`.  It is type-casting the `sf::String` from `getcwd()` to an ANSI encoded `std::string` (which is a *lossy* conversion), not to a UTF-8 encoded `std::string`.  But worse, that `sf::String` is being constructed by `getcwd()` from a UTF-8 encoded `std::string` but the `std::string` constructor of `sf::String` requires ANSI by default, not UTF-8 (to fix that, you have to give it a UTF-8 `std::locale`).  So, you are passing through several lossy conversions trying to get a string from the std::filesystem::path`returned from`std::filesystem::current_path`to`std::filesystem::directory_iterator`.

`sf::String` can convert to/from `std::wstring`, which `std::filesystem::path` can also use, so there is no need to go through UTF-8 and `std::filesystem::u8path()` at all, at least on Windows where `std::wstring` uses UTF-16 and Windows underlying filesystem APIs also use UTF-16.

Try this instead:

```cpp
bool neaxfile::isfile(const str &file) {
    std::wstring wstr = file;
    std::wcout << L"\nThis: " << wstr << L"\n";
    return std::filesystem::is_regular_file(std::filesystem::path(wstr));
}

str neaxfile::getcwd() {
    std::error_code ec;
    str path = std::filesystem::current_path(ec).wstring();
    if (ec.value() == 0) {
        return path;
    } else {
        return L"";
    }
}

std::vector<str> neaxfile::listfiles() {
    std::vector<str> res;
    std::filesystem::path cwdpath(neaxfile::getcwd().wstring());
    for (auto entry : std::filesystem::directory_iterator(cwdpath) {
        str filepath = entry.path().wstring();
        if (neaxfile::isfile(filepath)) res.push_back(filepath);
    }
    return res;
}
```

If you really want to use UTF-8 for conversions between C++ strings and SFML strings, then try this instead to avoid any data loss:

```cpp
std::string makeutf8str(const str &string) {
    auto utf8 = string.toUtf8();
    return std::string(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(utf8.c_str()), utf8.size());
}

str fromutf8str(const std::string &string) {
    return str::fromUtf8(utf8.begin(), utf8.end());
}

bool neaxfile::isfile(const str &file) {
    auto utf8 = makeutf8str(file);
    std::cout << "\nThis: " << utf8 << "\n";
    return std::filesystem::is_regular_file(std::filesystem::u8path(utf8));
}

str neaxfile::getcwd() {
    std::error_code ec;
    auto path = std::filesystem::current_path(ec).u8string();
    if (ec.value() == 0) {
        return fromutf8str(path);
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}

std::vector<str> neaxfile::listfiles() {
    std::vector<str> res;
    auto cwdpath = std::filesystem::u8path(makeutf8str(neaxfile::getcwd()));
    for (auto entry : std::filesystem::directory_iterator(cwdpath)) {
        str filepath = fromutf8str(entry.path().u8string());
        if (neaxfile::isfile(filepath)) res.push_back(filepath);
    }
    return res;
}
```

That being said, you are doing a lot of unnecessary conversions between C++ strings and SFML strings.  You really shouldn't be using SFML strings when you are not *directly* interacting with SFML's API.  You really should be using C++ strings as much as possible, especially with the `<filesystem>` API, eg:

```cpp
bool neaxfile::isfile(const std::string &file) {
    std::cout << L"\nThis: " << file << L"\n";
    return std::filesystem::is_regular_file(std::filesystem::u8path(file));
}

std::string neaxfile::getcwd() {
    std::error_code ec;
    std::string path = std::filesystem::current_path(ec).u8string();
    if (ec.value() == 0) {
        return path;
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}

std::vector<std::string> neaxfile::listfiles() {
    std::vector<std::string> res;
    auto cwdpath = std::filesystem::u8path(neaxfile::getcwd());
    for (auto entry : std::filesystem::directory_iterator(cwdpath)) {
        auto filepath = entry.path().u8string();
        if (neaxfile::isfile(filepath)) res.push_back(filepath);
    }
    return res;
}
```

Alternatively:

```cpp
bool neaxfile::isfile(const std::wstring &file) {
    std::wcout << L"\nThis: " << file << L"\n";
    return std::filesystem::is_regular_file(std::filesystem::path(file));
}

std::wstring neaxfile::getcwd() {
    std::error_code ec;
    auto path = std::filesystem::current_path(ec).wstring();
    if (ec.value() == 0) {
        return path;
    } else {
        return L"";
    }
}

std::vector<std::wstring> neaxfile::listfiles() {
    std::vector<std::wstring> res;
    std::filesystem::path cwdpath(neaxfile::getcwd());
    for (auto entry : std::filesystem::directory_iterator(cwdpath)) {
        auto filepath = entry.path().wstring();
        if (neaxfile::isfile(filepath)) res.push_back(filepath);
    }
    return res;
}
```

A better option is to simply not pass around strings at all.  `std::filesystem::path` is an abstraction to help shield you from that, eg:

```cpp
bool neaxfile::isfile(const std::filesystem::path &file) {
    std::wcout << L"\nThis: " << file.wstring() << L"\n";
    return std::filesystem::is_regular_file(file);
}

std::filesystem::path neaxfile::getcwd() {
    std::error_code ec;
    auto path = std::filesystem::current_path(ec);
    if (ec.value() == 0) {
        return path;
    } else {
        return {};
    }
}

std::vector<std::filesystem::path> neaxfile::listfiles() {
    std::vector<std::filesystem::path> res;
    for (auto entry : std::filesystem::directory_iterator(neaxfile::getcwd())) {
        auto filepath = entry.path();
        if (neaxfile::isfile(filepath)) res.push_back(filepath);
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution, it prints correctly but it still doesn't work. It has still confirmed that it's not a file.

Comment: I've added the code that i tried using above in the question i've edited. About the OS, i'm using windows and visual studio's compiler.

Comment: @AvaxarXapaxa You are mixing `str` with `std::string` incorrectly. `getcwd()` returns a UTF-8 `str` (BTW, why is it returning `'\0'` on failure? It should return `""` instead, which is not the same thing). You are *casting* that `str` to `std::string` (which is a *lossy* conversion to ANSI) instead of using it with `u8path()` to create a `path` (as I showed you earlier) for the `directory_iterator` to use. Your new code is not even using `u8path` at all.

Comment: `str` is `sf::String`, sorry to confuse you with that. Is there anyway i could fix this?

Comment: @AvaxarXapaxa I know what `str` is. The point is, you are not applying any of the code I gave you to the `directory_iterator`. Try this: `fs::directory_iterator(fs::u8path(makeutf8str(neaxfile::getcwd())))`

Comment: @AvaxarXapaxa except, I just realized that `sf::String` can convert to/from `std::wstring` directly, so you don't need UTF-8. I am updating my answer.

Comment: It doesn't work. Still, it prints `Яyes.txt` at the terminal correctly at `neaxfile::isfile()`, but when passed to `std::filesystem::is_regular_file()`, it returns false. I think `neaxfile::listfiles()` works correctly but the thing that determine if it's a file, don't which is `neaxfile::isfile()`